# Java: trouble understanding recursive method calling

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I made an 'Oregon Trail' like game, it uses a 'game over' method to ask if the user wants to play again.

The main issue:
My teacher mentioned something vague about if the game looped enough times, we'd end up with a stackOverflow. That makes sense to me because the game continues to nest methods inside of each other the way I have it, adding to the stack each time a 'new game' method is called because the outer methods are still there waiting to complete.

I've boiled down an example of what I mean. Assuming there were pauses for user input and such, how am I supposed to make sure my memory utilization doesn't keep growing as I call methods inside other methods? I think the word for this is 'recursive', thus my title.

If anyone could recommend correct form for dealing with this, I'd be really grateful.

```
public class Testing
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main method");
        gameStart();
    }
    
    private static void gameStart()
    {
        System.out.println("some other method called");
        gameOver();
    }
    
    private static void gameOver()
    {
        System.out.println("game over called"); //I would ask the user if they want to play again.
        //keeping it concise to illustrate my point, instead of using an if statement
        gameStart();//starting the cycle I'm concerned about. Assume the user indicated they would like to play again.
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use recursion in the assignment or would it be allowable to use a loop? Because using a loop would be the in my opinion easiest and most "natural" way to deal with this kind of situation.

Comment: I'd solve this particular issue with a loop, and not worry about recursion. Now, were we using LISP...

Comment: You can use try-catch with a `StackOverflowError`, and then deal with the overflow in the catch block. However, it's bad practice to catch errors so I wouldn't suggest it.

Comment: I do have to use recursion. There are bunches of loops in the program I made, but we are supposed to do this one without putting the entire game in a while or for loop.

Comment: by the way, thank you to everyone helping me. I'm just trying to figure out how keep calling methods that call each other, without overloading the stack. Like, could I clear the stack, retaining global variables, right when I call a new method somehow?

Comment: You normally run into `StackOverflowError` after the nesting reaches thousands or tens-of-thousands method calls, which usually implies a programming error (unless you've implemented an algorithm for something like [Towers of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) with really large values of `n`). So, unless you're taking the input from some kind of a program/AI, I wouldn't worry about exhausting the stack in your specific usage scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid unlimited recursion you may switch over to iteration and introduce return values for those methods which currently decide how to proceed (currently by directly calling the corresponding actions).
Let those methods return some sign what to do next, for example by using an enum.
Then write a loop which calls the right methods depending on the return values.

Example (abbreviated, I assume you know Java syntax):

```
enum Action { Start, ShowEnd, Quit }
```

main:

```
Action nextAction = Action.Start;
while (action != Action.Quit)
{
    switch (action)
    {
        case Start:
            nextAction = gameStart();
            break;
        case ShowEnd:
            nextAction = gameEnd();
            break;
        // ToDo: write more actions!
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This assumes that each such method executes until a decision was made about which action to take next.

This way your call stack will always be quite flat, as the execution always returns to the main method and then branches off into other methods.

Comment: don't really understand this answer entirely. However, I am dedicated to understanding what you've written. I know java syntax very well for what I've learned so far, but I don't understand your 'enum Action' line you've abbreviated. Is that supposed to be a different class? I haven't gotten to using multiple classes yet, but I can be there by tomorrow. I've looked at it for 5 minutes, and I don't understand. I assure you, I want to understand everything about what you've done. tbc...

Comment: It matters to me. However, I have yet to learn the concept you are abbreviating. I just want to say thank you for taking the time to answer me. It is very kind of you.

Comment: Okay, enums are not essential here. You can use simple numbers to indicate the next action instead (numbers are just not as descriptive as enums) - replace `Action.Start` and `Start` by `1`, `ShowEnd` by `2` and `Action.Quit` by `3`. Your method `gameEnd()` should return `1` (meaning Start) if the user decided to play again and it should return `3` (meaning Quit) if the user wants to quit. The main method will evaluate in the next loop iteration and perform the desired action.

Comment: In the real world this corresponds to this scenario: you (`main`) are the boss and have several specialized workers. You make one of them perform their task (call method) and you'll get a report which contains a suggestion what to do next (`nextAction`). Then you will look at that (`switch`), choose the worker which can perform the suggested action (`case ...`) and let it execute (method call)... This repeats (`while`) until the suggestion says you should stop.

Comment: The way you described this is very clear. I have yet to learn enums, but I will tonight. This, along with some other answers, has made my life easier. Thank you. This is more than some points on a website to me. You have helped me in a way my own teacher couldn't. Just, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion needs a condition where it will *not* continue calling.
Recursion is most commonly seen where a method calls *itself*, such as computing the fibonacci sequence, where

```
fib(n) == fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

`fib(0)` is defined as 0, so you don't have to compute.
`fib(1)` is defined as 1, so you don't have to compute.
Every other number is computed by the `fib()` method calling itself *twice*, but it escapes making the recursive call for the two defined cases, where there is nothing to compute. In pseudo code

```
int fib(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 0; // doesnt have to recursively call
    if (n == 1) return 1; // same
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

In your case, you have two methods that call *each other*, but you have no condition where the calls can escape from that.

A possibility would be that `gameOver()` only calls `gameStart()` when the game ends in a tie, something like

```
public class Testing
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main method");
        gameStart();
    }

    private static void gameStart()
    {
        System.out.println("some other method called");
        gameOver();
    }

    private static void gameOver()
    {
        System.out.println("game over called");
        if (gameTied()) {
            gameStart();
        }
    }
}
```

If you're just asking "do you want to play again?" -- that would be better done in `main`, along the lines of

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("main method");
    String playGame = "Yes";
    while (playGame.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") {
        gameStart();
        playGame = ask("Play again?");
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes so much sense. Thank you for helping me. I sincerely appreciate it. You're waiting until gameStart() completes to test the condition for playing again. Thank you so much for helping me. I do still wonder if it's possible to start a method and cancel the method from which it is nesting, but I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

When you write recursive code you should make sure that you have some sort of end condition BESIDES calling the function again. For example I added an end condition for the `gameOver` method with `if(gamePlayedThisManyTimes <= 1) return;`. When running the following code, the value you give the method `gameStart` will determine how many games you play and `gameOver` will decrement the value when it calls 'gameStart' to eventually reach that end condition of the recursion.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("main method");
    gameStart(10);
}

private static void gameStart(int playGameThisManyTimes)
{
    System.out.println("Game " + playGameThisManyTimes + " started...");
    System.out.println("some other method called");
    gameOver(playGameThisManyTimes);
}

private static void gameOver(int gamePlayedThisManyTimes)
{
    System.out.println("game over called for " + gamePlayedThisManyTimes); //I would ask the user if they want to play again.

    if(gamePlayedThisManyTimes <= 1)
        return;
    else
        gameStart(gamePlayedThisManyTimes - 1);
}
```

Output

```
main method
Game 10 started...
some other method called
game over called for 10
Game 9 started...
some other method called
game over called for 9
Game 8 started...
some other method called
game over called for 8
Game 7 started...
some other method called
game over called for 7
Game 6 started...
some other method called
game over called for 6
Game 5 started...
some other method called
game over called for 5
Game 4 started...
some other method called
game over called for 4
Game 3 started...
some other method called
game over called for 3
Game 2 started...
some other method called
game over called for 2
Game 1 started...
some other method called
game over called for 1
```

Comment: I didn't want to comment until I understood what you wrote. Thank you for your detailed answer. It just took me a minute to understand. I really appreciate the effort you've taken to help me.